# What are desired qualities of Moderator

Tags: discussion, election, moderators, moderator-abilities

What are desired qualities of Moderator?

While casting vote, how to identify best candidate among all others?

If the criteria were reputation, activity by review queue etc. no elections would be necessary. So what characteristics should I take into account choosing 'best' candidate?

Comment: Which one would you be most comfortable with having quite a bit of power over you and others?

Comment: Pick the ones who spend less time answering every thing that comes through no matter the scope/quality and more time editing/closing/voting/deleting

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian - What about the inverse of that situation?

Comment: I've voted to close this as too broad. While this is a potentially interesting question, I'm not sure there's a way to reasonably or objectively answer it in a truly all-encompassing way, and would thus become a list of possible reasons for voting... The fact of the matter is, there are dozens of qualities one can look for in a moderator, and to list them all would be a frivolous task. From my perspective, just vote for whoever makes sense and who you think would help the site the most, based on your best understanding.

Comment: Remember the time when you entered this resource? Which qualities of the SE founders you chose when you decided to trust your attention and time (learning, rank growth .. etc)? If you could look at those qualities of SE founder you would better grasp which of them to select more carefully. Though you couldn't make a claim to be another SE creator you could be one of the best educated moderators (with some limits of couse). So good luck to your choice, whenever you'd be a moderator or just want to elect one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from [Election Page](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1).

Community moderators are accorded the highest level of privilege on our community, and should themselves be exemplars of ***positive behavior*** and ***leaders*** within the community.

Our general criteria for moderators are as follows:

- ***patient and fair***
- leads by example
- shows ***respect for their fellow*** community members in their actions and words
- open to some light but firm moderation to keep the community on track and resolve (hopefully) uncommon disputes and exceptions

Apart from that you can select based on thier ***activities***. ***achievements*** so far in the community

I always take help of the current mods comment under the candidate nominations. It really help us to vote the most deserving one.

Comment: Well, for it to even be possible to be on the list, you already have to rank pretty high I'm that. As MeNoTalk pointed out, it's the collective community that decides.

Answer (score 0):

If there were a list of well-known specific qualities, then SE would have not made the process of electing moderators a public one. The main quality IMO is: acceptance by people. You should elect someone you know (through their answers, questions, comments, chats, etc.).

Even if there were a list of a specific qualities, as long as the process is public, then the community's opinion is what has the final word. So pick up your next moderator according to the qualities you wish them to have (in accordance with SE goals of course).